# Getting ng-model value onclick angulajs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I want to get ng-model's value in angular function

```
<div id="script">
<div ng-repeat="selected in multiselectfields" id="generatedscript" ng-model="script">
"Insert into {{selected}} {{rules}}"
</div>
<input type="button" value="Generate PDF" ng-click="generatePDF();"/>
</div>
```

and angular function is

```
$scope.generatePDF = function() {
 var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('generatedscript').textContent;
console.log(document.getElementById('generatedscript').innerHTML);
};
```

Its showing only first line which is created dynamically like
"Insert into idnumber 1"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try this `$scope.generatePDF = function() {
console.log($scope.script);
};` it will give you the `ng-model` value.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use `document.getElementById`, you can directly print the ng-model **`scope`** variable

```
$scope.generatePDF = function() {
console.log("Insert into " + $scope.selected);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value of `ng-model` directly to your function:
In HTML as `ng-click="generatePDF(script)"`

and get that value in controller as:

```
$scope.generatePDF = function(script) {
     console.log("Insert into " + script);
};
```